# Veneer on pine wood lumber 25CM

Tags: veneer

I want to glue veneer on pine lumber wood 25x25 cm, is that possible? or the veneer will not hold?

Comment: I'm curious. What makes you think that the veneer won't hold in this application?

Comment: Pine was actually a common core wood (substrate) in traditional European veneered furniture. But there are some other considerations you will need to investigate fully before you begin. Assuming the veneer you choose is not self-adhesive the first thing you need to work out is which glue to use. Also very important for long-term looks is how stable the substrate is — ideally you want it to be straight-grained, with minimal or zero knots. Remember that most modern veneer is *very* thin compared to old veneers, so slight imperfections show through to the surface much more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't it?

[Marquetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquetry) has been done for centuries and involves gluing hundreds or thousands of tiny slivers of veneer pieces to a larger surface to make a pattern.

There's no reason a single larger sheet of veneer wouldn't stick to a 25 x 25cm piece of pine. The key is in the prep work, not in the size of the material.

Comment: Or the fact that the underlying material is pine..

Comment: @gnicko please expand - I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: I'm saying that the fact that it's pine shouldn't be a concern either.